# R: call to lapply w/ nearest neighbors library yields error

Tags: r

Setting it up:

```
library(kknn)

event <- c('first', 'second', 'third', 'second', 'second', 'third', 'third', 'first')
speed <- c(1.25, 2.22, 3.02, 4.22, 1.56, 2.77, 3.21, 1.55)
time <- c(667, 444, 335, 204, 393, 949, 203, 365)

model <- event ~ speed + time

df <- data.frame(event, speed, time)
```

This works fine:

```
data <- df[1,]
fit <- kknn(model, df, data, k=2, kernel="gaussian")
fit$prob
```

But building a function to use in iteration does not:

```
k_fit <- function(data) {
    fit <- kknn(model, df, data, k=2, kernel="gaussian")
    out <- as.data.frame(fit$prob)
}

lapply(df, k_fit)
```

Yields:

```
> lapply(df, k_fit)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
Calls: lapply ... model.matrix.default -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval
Execution halted
```

What's wrong w/ the iterative approach here? Thank you.

Comment: `lapply` loops over list elements. Data frames are lists of columns. You're looping over the columns, not the rows.

Comment: What would be the adjustment to have it properly loop over the rows of data in the frame?

Comment: Use a `for` loop, I suppose, although it's not really clear to me why you're running knn on one data point at a time.

Comment: Equivalent to a `for`, you can use `lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x)kfit(df[x,]))`, or you could use `by` to subset the `data.frame`: `by(df,1:nrow(df),k_fit)`

Comment: Also, doing `lapply(split(df, 1:1), k_fit)` seems to do what I want by making a list of data frames, but I'm not sure if that's a terrible hacky solution.

Comment: I think you mean `lapply(split(df,1:nrow(df)),k_fit)`, which is exactly what `by` does. But, as @joran points out, you probably don't want to run the model on a single point of data, I am guessing you want to run the model on successively bigger samples (rows 1, then rows 1 and 2, then rows 1:3).